# Pytorch median - is it bug or am I using it wrong

Tags: python, pytorch, median, torch

I am trying to get median of each row of 2D torch.tensor. But the result is not what I expect when compared to working with standard array or numpy

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from statistics import median

print(torch.__version__)
>>> 0.4.1

y = [[1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1],[1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1]]
median(y[0])
>>> 2.5

np.median(y,axis=1)
>>> array([2.5, 2.5])

yt = torch.tensor(y,dtype=torch.float32)
yt.median(1)[0]
>>> tensor([2., 2.])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is the intended behaviour of Torch as mentioned in this issue

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1837
https://github.com/torch/torch7/pull/182

The reasoning as mentioned in the link above

> Median returns 'middle' element in case of odd-many elements, otherwise one-before-middle element (could also do the other convention to take mean of the two around-the-middle elements, but that would be twice more expensive, so I decided for this one).

Comment: Thank you, I will use numpy then. Its not a big deal.

Comment: Can I emulate real mean through other functions?

Comment: `x.quantile(q=0.5)` gives you the same behavior as `np.median(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate numpy median with pytorch:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
y =[1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1]
print("numpy=",np.median(y))
print(sorted([1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1]))
yt = torch.tensor(y,dtype=torch.float32)
ymax = torch.tensor([yt.max()])
print("torch=",yt.median())
print("torch_fixed=",(torch.cat((yt,ymax)).median()+yt.median())/2.)
```